# display hidden doesn't work with media query

Tags: css, media-queries

Even though I have added `display:none` or `display:hidden`, the container doesn't hide.

**Code:**

```
 <div className="button-container">
      <div className="cart-button" style={{ marginRight: "20px" }}>
        <p style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Login</p>
      </div>
      <div className="cart-button">
        <p style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Cart</p>
      </div>
    </div>

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .button-container {
    display: hidden;
  }
}
```

Codesandbox link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-platform-yzcz6m?file=/src/styles.css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting display to `none` works. I checked it on your codesandbox fork.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .button-container {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div className="button-container">
      <div className="cart-button" style={{ marginRight: "20px" }}>
        <p style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Login</p>
      </div>
      <div className="cart-button">
        <p style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Cart</p>
      </div>
    </div>

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .button-container {
    visability: hidden;
  }
}
```

Comment: I use reactjs and also replacing doesn't work.

Comment: i'm sorry. try to visibility: hidden;

Answer (score 0):

Try "none" instead of "hidden". with display

display:none

Comment: Tried, doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

Try "visibility" instead of "display".

visibility: hidden;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).